# Segue from SwiftUI to Storyboard View Controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, segue

I have a SwiftUI app with ContentView() that I then want to send the user to a View Controller with a Storyboard. what's the best way to accomplish this? I can't figure out how to connect the two.

App.swift code is pretty basic:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, in my ContentView.swift, I handle the user login and would then like to send them to a storyboard view controller via a segue:

```
import SwiftUI
import CloudKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        // ...login code
        
        // segue...do I use a NavigationLink? Couldn't get that to work here.
```

Would it be easier to just convert the ContentView into a storyboard as well? If so, how can I go about that in the App.swift file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567727/how-to-add-storyboard-viewcontroller-into-swiftui-project?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure I fully understand, no. Do I navigation link to the VC or can I segue?

Comment: actually I think an easier way to fix this would be to simply just open the storyboard in the App.Swift file instead of the ContentView. Is there a way to do that @Asperi?