# possible to instantiate WKInterfaceController in SwiftUI Watch project?

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch

I have a project in which I have run into a limitation of SwiftUI on the Apple Watch. My proposed solution was to instantiate a WKInterfaceController to perform the needed functionality, and then return to using SwiftUI views. Is this possible? I tried to wrap my controller in a WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable object, but there doesn't seem to way to instantiate the interface controller from a Storyboard, as is possible on iOS according to this similar case:

[How to add Storyboard ViewController into SwiftUI Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567727/how-to-add-storyboard-viewcontroller-into-swiftui-project)

But Xcode tells me, "Cannot find UIStoryboard in scope"

Is there a way to create an InterfaceController from SwiftUI? Or perhaps I need to use a WKHostingController for my whole Watch project, so as to have access to the option of using InterfaceController objects?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: UIStoryboard is part of UIKit, not SwiftUI, and it is not available for Apple Watch watchOS. Use either pure SwiftUI or WatchKit.

Comment: OK...but storyboard is used in WatchKit projects. But perhaps there is just no way to refer to it programmatically?

Comment: Did you find the solutions for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to an existing interface controller defined in a watchOS storyboard from SwiftUI by using `NavigationLink` with the `destinationName:label:` arguments, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destinationname:label:)).

`destinationName` is the identifier used in the storyboard for that interface controller, eg:

```
NavigationLink(destinationName: "MyInterfaceControllerIdentifier") {
  Text("Go")
}
```